# Открыть базу данных .db в python

Tags: python, sqlite3

Пишу такой код:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("C:\\Users\\Acer\\db.db")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("select * from db;")
results = cur.fetchall()
print(results)
```

Вывод:

> OperationalError: no such table: db.

Если без расширения, вывод тот же.
Эта БД, вместе с тем, лежит в той же директории. что находится по pwd. Что не так? Спасибо.

Comment: а таблица в бд тоже `db` ?

Comment: `db.db` - это у вас база. Вы к базе успешно подключились, и пытаетесь получить данные из таблицы с именем db, и ошибка говорит о том что такой таблицы в базе нет. Либо просто этой таблицы нет, и нужно смотреть сначала, какие там таблицы вообще есть, либо вы просто базу только создали пустую, естественно в пустой базе не будет ни таблицы db, ни какой либо другой (кроме каких-нибудь служебных).

Comment: чтобы получить список всех таблиц в SQLite файле: `cur.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'"); print(cur.fetchall())`

Answer (score 2):

Выдаёт вам ошибку по той причине, что такой таблицы "db" не существует.
Используйте:

```
cur.execute('SELECT * from sqlite_master where type= "table"')
result = cur.fetchall()
print(result)
```

Comment: ааа. конечно же, спасибо большое. БД - это же совокупность таблиц, не таблица..

Comment: Versteher, вы всегда можете назвать таблицу db, ошибку то вам выдаёт по поводу того, что такой таблицы не существует. Если мой ответ вам подошёл - примите его, пожалуйста.